# bootstrap inline text and dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, css

I'm trying to align a text with a drop down menu but so far the drop down menu has a great width preventing it from aligning with the text.

here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <h2 class="col-md-3">Your Entries by</h2>
            <select class="col-md-3 form-control input-lg">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="year">Year</option>
            <option value="month">Month</option>
            <option value="week">Week</option>
            <option value="day">Day</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

I want this to look like "Your Entries by `<drop down>`"

but so far it goes like this:

"Your Entries by"

```
<drop down>
```

I know this is pretty simple but i'm afraid of tinkering with the width as it may cause some problems with the responsive template. any ideas on this?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to align?

Comment: @DavidG the <h2> and the dropdown :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are slightly misusing the `col-*` classes. Instead of combining them with your classes, use them in wrapper divs, like below. Also, to have an inline form as you require, add the `.form-inline` class:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <h2>Your Entries by</h2>
    <select class="form-control input-lg">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="year">Year</option>
      <option value="month">Month</option>
      <option value="week">Week</option>
      <option value="day">Day</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/B8nviK3l8i

Comment: i'm sorry but there were some missing elements in my question that may have confused you, i've updated them now. also thanks for that info :)